# How to display 3CX call reports in MS Dynamics CRM 2013?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013, 3cx

What I want is to instead of getting a call report on call reporting module on my phone system server, I want to reach the same one within MS Dynamics CRM 2013.

Software that I use are Windows 7 64-bit, Dynamics CRM 2013 with installed 3CX CRM Integration Module, 3CX Phone System PRO.

During the configuration of MS Dynamics CRM plugin I checked the checkbox "store call information in Microsoft Dynamics".

Does that allow me to view 3CX call reports within Dynamics CRM 2013? And if yes, where I can find it?

If above is not the case, is there any other solution to solve my request? 
I also tried to find 3CX API (on official 3CX web page) which provide that feature but nothing.

Comment: Wouldn't it be more appropriate to contact the vendor suport?

Answer (score 0):

1. This tool will let you export the call data from 3CX into a standard SQL database.

   http://www.voiptoys.com/3cx-exporter-for-call-detail-records
2. You'll want to create a custom entity in Dynamics CRM that matches the data as you've exported it into your SQL database through the exporter tool.
3. Then after you've done that, you can write a simple CRM Plugin for Dynamics to read the call data from SQL into the custom CRM Entity.
4. You then make your reports based off of that entity.